# To get all open panels in an array on refresh

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable, bootstrap-accordion

I am implementing a collapsible panel using Bootstrap Collapse as shown in this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gYa3/585/) with a few modifications.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Body1
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Body 2
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
      Collapsible Group Item #3
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Body 3
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
/* symbol for "opening" panels */
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
/* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

I also have the page to reload every 60 seconds.All my panels on page load are closed by default. I need to store all the panels that are open and then put it back into open after refresh. 
This code will give me all the tabs instead of only the open tabs.

```
myArray = $('.accordion-toggle');
```

How do I get all the panels that are open into an array and then make them open after the page refresh? If i get all the panels that are open I can remove the collapsed class from them.
EDIT 1:

```
headerArray = $('.accordion-toggle').find('a[aria-expanded=true]').closest('div');
```

This gives me only the first div and not all the divs in the page.

Answer (score 1):

As i have seen that [aria-expanded] attribute got change when collapse or expand so i have just find list of anchor tags where [area-expanded] opened and find closest div for Panel which you want to store in array.

myArray = $('#accordion').find('a[aria-expanded=true]').closest('div')

Comment: How do I find all divs? This is giving me only the first occurrence.

Comment: I have create sample on Jsfiddle and put a alert which return #no of divs.
Please refer link below.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahul25890/3gYa3/1209/)